# Multiple glossaries don't work with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, glossaries, glossary

I started working on a book project using TexPad for Mac (now called Texifier) which uses some kind of proprietary engine. It did however have issues with the fontspec package which I absolutely need, so I switched to TeXShop. There I'm using XeLaTeX which works pretty well and solved lots of the font related issues I previously had. Unfortunately, the glossaries are not displayed anymore, or rather, only the main glossary is, but everything else doesn't work (it did work with TexPad).

I have created a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,numberedsection,ucmark,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\newglossary[ppl]{person}{ppx}{ppy}{People}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{p1.tex}
\loadglsentries{gls1.tex}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\begin{appendices}
    \printglossary[type=person]
    \printglossary
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Here, I'm adding two glossary files, *p1.tex* and *gls1.tex*. The latter one contains the main glossary and is displayed correctly. The entries therein look like this:

```
\newglossaryentry{lexicography}
{
    name={Lexicography},
    description={The study of semantic and orthographic features of words and their roots as well as the study of sounds, words, grammatical phrases, sentences, and their relationships.}
}
```

In this example, I only have one more glossary type. These entries are not displayed in the output file. The entries look like this:

```
\newglossaryentry{Löw Brill}
{
    type=person,
    name={Loew Brill, Samuel},
    description={(1814–1897 AD), a Hungarian Rabbi and Talmudical scholar. Attending the Talmud schools at Eisenach and Prague, he received his rabbinical degree at the age of 22. In his native city of Budabest he soon becomes widely known for his Talmudic lectures.}
}
```

Glossary entries with a *type* are not displayed at all.

I've zipped all the files of this minimal example and put it on my dropbox:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/shgurgemlicg95m/Test.zip?dl=0

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: looks ok on windows. make a zip file out of your mwe with all the log-files and put it somewhere for inspection.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, I've added a link to the zip file.

Comment: there is no log for the person glossary. How are you calling makeglossaries?

Comment: I have added an engine to TeXShop. It looks like this:

#!/bin/sh

bfname=$(dirname "$1")/"`basename "$1" .tex`"

makeindex -s "$bfname".ist -t "$bfname".alg -o "$bfname".acr "$bfname".acn
makeindex -s "$bfname".ist -t "$bfname".glg -o "$bfname".gls "$bfname".glo

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That was a good hint. When I run `makeglossaries` from the Terminal it works fine. So it must be the TeXShop engine which is responsible for the issue. I hope I can figure it out from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer, I figured it out. Turns out it wasn't a XeLaTeX issue but a TeXShop issue, at least an issue with the way I had set it up. When I run `makeglossaries` from the Terminal, everything works fine. Meaning that one way or another, I'll be able to finish my project, even if I don't figure out how to do it from TeXShop.